# Testing for an error not being thrown by an async function

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to test for an error not being thrown, and I've done the following in my test:

```
await expect(() => execute(1, 1)).rejects.not.toThrow()
```

The test fails when `execute` throws an error, as I want it to. However, when `execute` resolves successfully, I get the following test failure:

```
Received promise resolved instead of rejected
Resolved to value: undefined
```

I've previously used Jasmine for this sort of thing, and it happily does `expect(() => codeThrowingError).not.toThrow()`, but the syntax for Jest seems a bit more tortured and I'm not sure how to get this right.

Comment: If you expect it *not* to reject (noting that this isn't the same as throwing an error), maybe `.resolves.toEqual(expect.anything())`?

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. Thanks, my brain is obviously too full today!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Works great with https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe response about doing `await expect(execute(1, 1)).resolves.toEqual(expect.anything())`

Comment: That won't work, only `.toThrow` and the related expectations call a function passed to `expect`. It'll fail with `Matcher error: received value must be a promise` because `Received has type:  function`. You need to pass the promise directly, for example `await expect(Promise.reject("uh oh!")).resolves.toEqual(expect.anything())` would fail for the correct reason: `Received promise rejected instead of resolved`, `Rejected to value: "uh oh!"`

Comment: No, it does. Execute is an async function returning a promise, so () => execute(1, 1) returns the promise. And it works as expected in my test, so thanks

Comment: `execute(1, 1)` is the promise, `() => execute(1, 1)` is a function returning a promise. When I ran the code you've posted in Jest locally (with `const execute = (x, y) => Promise.resolve({ x, y });`), I got the errors I mentioned above. [`.toThrow...`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror) is what calls functions passed to expect, the other expectations do not. Are you awaiting/returning the asynchronous expectation?

Comment: Apologies, yes, I'm doing `await expect(() => execute(1, 1)).resolves.toEqual(expect.anything())`

Comment: Updated answer to reflect this

Comment: I've just run it again locally. Given `const execute = (x, y) => Promise.resolve({ x, y });`, if I run the test `it("shouldn't reject", async () => { await expect(() => execute(1, 1)).resolves.toEqual(expect.anything()); });`, it **fails**, because `received value must be a promise` but `Received has type:  function`. **Only `.toThrow...` calls a function passed as `actual`**, because the throwing of an error *needs* to be deferred.

Comment: But if you do `const execute = async (x, y) => {x , y}`, the `await expect(execute(1, 1)).resolves.toEqual(expect.anything())` works, which is an acceptable solution for me.

Comment: Yes, because you're now passing the promise `execute(1, 1)` not the function `() => execute(1, 1)`, as I've been saying all along. And `const execute = async (x, y) => {x , y}` resolves to nothing.